# Simple find-and replace regexp

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

In a .txt file i have multiple lines. Every line contains timing data like this:

```
time [4.1s] [4100ms]
time [5.53s] [5530ms]
```

All lines have different words/chars before and after the times.

I want to do a Find- and replace action (In Notepad++) to get the following, simple, format:

```
4.1
5.53
```

How do I do it? What is the regular expression to use?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
.*\[([\d.]+)s\].*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want the first number in brackets and that has a decimal point as per your example:

```
\d*[.]\d+
```

This returns `4.1` and `5.53` as requested when applied to your example.

If the first number might not have a decimal point, then you want to consider:

```
\d*[.]?\d+s
```

but append `s` in your replace to account for the s.

**Update**

Update based on your latest information. I don't know if Notepad++ supports positive lookbehind (`?<=`), but if it does you could do this:

```
(?<=time \[)\d*[.]\d+
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! acarlons solution almost works. However - and I should probably should have told this - there can be brackets and decimal numbers both before and after "time..[] []" which is not interesting for me.